# How to change action bar background color on holding home button?

Tags: android, colors, android-actionbar

I had changed Action Bar color with this code: `getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0067ad")));`
But when I hold Home button there Action Bar Color is Black. 
How I can change it!
Thanks![image]

Answer (score 0):

You'd better set color of Actionbar in styles-v21.xml like following:

```
<item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/yourActionbarColor</item>
```

colorPrimary determines the color of Actionbar and app's header in recents. In styles.xml focused on pre-L versions, you should use `name="colorPrimary"` to get same result.

And if you only want to change header color shown in recents above Lollipop, you can use following java code:

```
TaskDescription taskDesc = new TaskDescription(yourTitle, yourIcon, yourColor);
myActivity.setTaskDescription(taskDesc);
```